# Pandas pivot columns based on column name prefix

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-melt

I have a dataframe:

```
df = AG_Speed AG_wolt AB_Speed AB_wolt C1 C2 C3
       1         2      3         4     6  7  8
       1         9      2         6     4  1  8
```

And I want to pivot it based on prefix to get:

```
df = Speed Wolt C1 C2 C3 Category
      1      2   6 7  8    AG
      3      4   6 7  8    AB
      1      9   4 1  8    AG
      2      6   4 1  8    AG
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for this. But since it expects the column names to start with the stubnames, we have to reverse the column format:

```
df.columns = ["_".join(col.split("_")[::-1]) for col in df.columns]
res = pd.wide_to_long(
    df, 
    stubnames=["Speed", "wolt"], 
    i=["C1", "C2", "C3"], 
    j="Category", 
    sep="_", 
    suffix="[A-Za-z]+"
).reset_index()
```

```
   C1  C2  C3 Category  Speed  wolt
0   6   7   8       AG      1     2
1   6   7   8       AB      3     4
2   4   1   8       AG      1     9
3   4   1   8       AB      2     6
```

If you want the columns in a specific order, use `DataFrame.reindex`:

```
res.reindex(columns=["Speed", "wolt", "C1", "C2", "C3", "Category"])
```

```
   Speed  wolt  C1  C2  C3 Category
0      1     2   6   7   8       AG
1      3     4   6   7   8       AB
2      1     9   4   1   8       AG
3      2     6   4   1   8       AB
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], 
                names_to = ('Category', '.value'), 
                names_sep='_')

   C1  C2  C3 Category  Speed  wolt
0   6   7   8       AG      1     2
1   4   1   8       AG      1     9
2   6   7   8       AB      3     4
3   4   1   8       AB      2     6
```

In the above solution, the `.value` determines which parts of the column labels remain as headers - the labels are split apart with the `names_sep`.